# How to merge multiple dataframes with the same number of columns into one dataframe that shows all of the column headers per individual frame? -Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

In Pandas, I am able to concatenate 3 different dataframes together, where they all have a certain amount of columns headers in common, but just 1 different initial column header. However, the common/shared headers between the frames are only showed once, at the top of the CSV file/Excel sheet. Example (where fruit is a separate dataframe from plants):

```
*fruit* | *plants* | run 1 | run 2 | run 3 | max |
 papaya |          | 22    |  21   | 21    | 22  |
 orange |          | 20    |  2    | 2     | 20  |
        | mint     | 12    |  22   | 1.3   | 22  |
        | cactus   | 13    |  23   | 20    | 23  |
```

What I am really trying to get is this, so once larger data comes in, it's easier to visualize without always having to scroll up constantly:

```
*fruit* | run 1 | run 2 | run 3 | max |
 papaya | 22    |  21   |  21   | 22  |
 orange | 20    |  2    |  2    | 20  |
        |       |       |       |     |
*plants*| run 1 | run2  | run 3 | max |
 mint   | 12    | 22    | 1.3   | 22  |
 cactus | 13    | 23    | 20    | 23  |
```

-Also, I apologize if I am using concat function instead of merge or join function. I really don't see how they produce different output. I am still studying the difference between them. Does anyone know if this is possible to do with Python and Pandas?

Here is my current code for concatenating them (as shown in diagram 1):

```
largeData = pd.concat([fruitsFrame, plantsFrame], axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the different column into index and then concat them:

```
pd.concat([plantsFrame.set_index(['plants']), fruitsFrame.set_index(['fruit'])])
```

Output:

```
      run 1 run 2   run 3   max
mint    12  22      1.3     22
cactus  13  23      20.0    23
papaya  22  21      21.0    22
orange  20  2       2.0     20
```

Comment: Thanks, however this does completely erase the "fruit" and "plants" headers, which are needed for easy reading of the data by the user. Is there any way to preserve that? If I find anything I will update this post.

Comment: You cannot have two hears in the same df. I guess, you can create a new column which says if it is a fruit or a plant. I will update my answer, if that satisfies your need.

Comment: Yes, if possible, may you focus in on my question a little more? Your original answer doesn't answer it. Thank you.